# name for table representing solution of $a + b = c$ over finite groups?

Tags: finite-groups, notation

I have a table whose row and column headings are given by $r, c \in X$ respectively where $X$ is a finite group $(X, +)$. Table cell entries $T[r, c] = \lbrace x : r + x = c, \ \forall x \in X \rbrace$. Is there a name for this table / representation?

Comment: Is your group operation $\cdot$ or $+$? Also, this is similar to a [Cayley Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table), although not precisely the same thing.

Comment: I'd call it the *subtraction table*, with maybe a footnote or parenthetical remark saying it's morally the same thing as the Cayley table.

Comment: @Mark cleared up notation. The Cayley Table is similar, but certainly different.

Comment: It's not really that different actually.  The cayley table has $x = c+r$ in each entry, you have $x = c-r$ in each entry.  So, if you just map each $r\mapsto r^{-1}$ and re-label the rows, you get a cayley table.

Comment: @Mark or to be precise $x = -r+c$.

Comment: Well, we called them "subtraction tables" when I was in the first grade. I don't see any reason to change now.

Comment: @Mark, hadn't thought about it that way, but see your point. Thanks.